# Remove scrollbar from div tag CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have set a div tag with background as svg file.But it shows scrollbar ..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbkgw

This is the code...I WANT TO REMOVE THE SCROLLBAR ...

```
<div id="c"></div>

#c
{
width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: url('http://www.festember.com/14/images/temp/Header/logo.svg');
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border:1px solid tomato;
  background-size:100px 100px;
}
```

Image ::

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3EGa.png

Comment: see this image   http://i.stack.imgur.com/d3EGa.png ...

Comment: I think that bug was fixed in Chrome 37, in any case I see no scrollbars in Chrome 38. A possible workaround might be to add `overflow="hidden"` to the root svg (inside logo.svg).

Answer (score 0):

Have this css included if you having a scrollbar

```
overflow:hidden;
```

So your class will look like

```
#c
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: url('http://www.festember.com/14/images/temp/Header/logo.svg');
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border:1px solid tomato;
  background-size:100px 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Update: it may not work on container which has images so need to wrap it up with another div

```
<div id ="wrapper">
  <div id="c"></div>
</div>
```

And css

```
#wrapper {
   overflow:hidden;
}

#c
{
width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: url('http://www.festember.com/14/images/temp/Header/logo.svg');
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border:1px solid tomato;
  background-size:100px 100px;
}
```

Comment: Which browser you trying on?

Comment: Google chrome v.36 ...see this image for more info http://i.stack.imgur.com/d3EGa.png

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox I'm not seeing any srcollbar, but on Chrome and IE is not the same case. I researched this and tried a few thing but the scrollbar is still there in Chrome.

I thing that a simple picture of the logo may save you time and fix the problem. Making the circle with the logo inside - 10 minutes on Photoshop.

Example (HTML):\

```
  <div id ="wrapper">
   <a class="logo" title="Company" href="home.html">
    <img alt="Company's logo" src="images/logo.png">
   </a>
  </div>
```

The `margin: 10px auto;` is in the `logo` class and you are done.